# Attempting to make code more efficient and implement JQuery toggle-like methods without breaking operability

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, twitter-bootstrap-3, show-hide

Using Bootstrap 3 tabs, JQuery 1.10. Coding level: immature.

I'm trying to set up a simple click nav function which will allow me to click through a set of dynamically added elements on loop (divs, imgs, textnodes).

I have created the following (verbose) js:

```
var upButton = document.getElementById("up");
var downButton = document.getElementById("down");
var colors = $(".color");
var count = 0;

$("#color" + count).show();

$(upButton).click(function(){
    if ((count-1) < 0) {
        count = (colors.length - 1);
        }
    else {
        count = count-1;
        };
    $(".color").hide();
    $("#color" + count).show();
});

$(downButton).click(function(){
    if ((count + 1) > (colors.length-1)) {
        count = 0;
        }
    else {
        count = count + 1;
        };
    $(".color").hide();
    $("#color" + count).show();
});
```

And HTML:

```
<body>
    <div type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" id = "up"> Up </div>
    <div type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" id = "down"> Down </div>
    <div class = "color-group">
        <div id="color0" class="color red">
            <h1>Red</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="color1" class="color orange">
            <h1>Orange</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="color2" class="color yellow">
            <h1>Yellow</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="color3" class="color green">
            <h1>Green</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="color4" class="color blue">
            <h1>Blue</h1>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>

</body>
```

You can watch it in action at jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chaimfulhack/uLfAR/

I have a style question and practice question.

First, I would like to make this code more efficient and while preserving its readability and its ability to work with a given set of classes/ids. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Second, I would like to consider other JQuery methods of transitioning from one element to the next such as slideToggle() or toggle should I want to add effects later, but I'm having a challenging time recreating these results.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses no ID's and adds in use of `eq(index)` , a `filter(':visible')` and use of `next()` and `prev()` for traverses. As for efificiency...it may or may not be more efficent processing wise but represents a few new concepts that might be interesting for you. Also uses `is()` and `length` as tests on elements in jQuery collection

```
var $colors = $(".color");
/* show first content element*/
$colors.eq(0).show();/* eq(index)*/

$('#up,#down').click(function(){
    /* "this" is current button clciked*/
    var $currColor=$colors.filter(':visible'),
         direction_is_up=$(this).is('#up'),
         $next;

    if(direction_is_up){
        /* check if there is a "next()" if not go to first*/
        $next = $currColor.next().length ? $currColor.next() : $colors.first();     
    }else{
       $next = $currColor.prev().length ? $currColor.prev() : $colors.last();  
    }

    $currColor.fadeOut(function(){
        /* callback fires after animation completed, start next animation here*/
        $next.fadeIn() 
    }); 

});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uLfAR/3/)**</kbd>

Can [***Read the API docs***](http://api.jquery.com/) for methods used. Keep API bookmarked and refer to it often

Note: use of `$` prefix is a common practice to denote a variable is a jQuery object. Is not required, simply a convenience protocol for reading code

Comment: I like both of these options (thank you @kardossandor) and will test to see how they implement in my block of code I'm developing. One quick question: is there a benefit to using `.click` over `.on('click', function....`?

Comment: no benefit using `click` vs `on('clcik`... first is shortcut for second

Comment: Thank you. Seems to be working quite well in implementation. However, I am still hitting the wall. As I mentioned, I am applying this to multiple tabs. The `:visible` filter will pull up each tab's color.eq(0). I've been trying three approaches. Could you make a recommendation? I figure I could: (1) insert a specific attribute per tab, (2) use `.siblings()`,  or (3) use a different filter such as `:focus`.

Comment: Nevermind! Understanding `this` made all the difference! I think I have it.

Comment: whenever working with repeating `modules` you always want to isolate everything within current instance. So you typically traverse to parent of instance and use `find` within that instance to isolate to componnets only within that instance of the module

Comment: Here is demo with 2 instances...only a couple of extra lines of code added and html class to wrap each instance  http://jsfiddle.net/uLfAR/9/

Comment: Got it done! I forgot to isolate my buttons per instance, so when I got to my nth tab, I was seeing erratic behavior with my buttons. Now to clean up my code. You've been a big help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Shows first element with the class of color
$(".color:first-child").addClass("show");

// Caches jQuery objects
var up = $("#up");
var down = $("#down");


// Sets up the click event on UP
$("#up").on("click", function(){

    // Checks if there's any next element
    if ( $(".show").next().length ) {

        // Removes the show class from the actual element
        // Adds show class to the element next to the actual
        $(".show").add( $(".show").next() ).toggleClass("show");

    } else {

        // Resets to the first element
        $(".show").add( $(".color:first-child") ).toggleClass("show");

    }

});

$("#down").on("click", function(){
    if ( $(".show").prev().length ) {
        $(".show").add( $(".show").prev() ).toggleClass("show");
    } else {
        $(".show").add( $(".color:last-child") ).toggleClass("show");
    }
});
```

You should not use more than one h1 tag on a page. [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/uLfAR/5/)